# Formatting Specific Variables in an Array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, outlook

I get information from an Excel spreadsheet and put it in an email message to be sent.

I have a table to be displayed at the end of the message. I create the table with HTML, with variables populated by an array, to more efficiently create these variables.

One of the columns of the table is supposed to be formatted with percentages and one other as currency. How can I format just those variables while still keeping the array?

```
Sub email()

Dim mailsubject As String       'Variable that carries the subject of the email
Dim mailbody As String          'Variable that carries the body of the email
Dim tabledata(2 To 7, 21 To 28) As String
Dim i As Integer                'i and j are auxiliary variables to create the array
Dim j As Integer

'::::::::::::::Among these are the variables I want to format:::::::::::::::

For i = 2 To 7

    For j = 21 To 28

        tabledata(i, j) = Cells(i, j).Value            

'::::::::::::::tabledata(3 to 7, 27) needs to be formatted as percentage, and tabledata(3 to 7, 28) as percentage with two decimal digits.:::::::::::::::::::

    Next

Next

Dim OutlookApp As Outlook.Application
Dim MItem As Outlook.mailitem

Set OutlookApp = New Outlook.Application

mailsubject = "PRODUCT IDEA"

mailbody = "<TABLE BORDER='1'    WIDTH='10%'   CELLPADDING='1' CELLSPACING='1'><TR><TH COLSPAN='8'><BR><H3></H3>" _
               & "</TH></TR><TR><TH>" & tabledata(2, 21) & "</TH><TH>" & tabledata(2, 22) & "</TH><TH>" & tabledata(2, 23) & "</TH><TH>" & tabledata(2, 24) _
               & "</TH><TH>" & tabledata(2, 25) & "</TH><TH>" & tabledata(2, 26) & "</TH><TH>" & tabledata(2, 27) & "</TH><TH>" & tabledata(2, 28) & "</TH></TR>" _
               & "<TR><TD>" & tabledata(3, 21) & "</TD><TD>" & tabledata(3, 22) & "</TD><TD>" & tabledata(3, 23) & "</TD><TD>" & tabledata(3, 24) & "</TD>" _
               & "<TD>" & tabledata(3, 25) & "</TD><TD>" & tabledata(3, 26) & "</TD><TD>" & tabledata(3, 27) & "</TD><TD>" & tabledata(3, 28) & "</TD></TR>" _
               & "<TR><TD>" & tabledata(4, 21) & "</TD><TD>" & tabledata(4, 22) & "</TD><TD>" & tabledata(4, 23) & "</TD><TD>" & tabledata(4, 24) & "</TD>" _
               & "<TD>" & tabledata(4, 25) & "</TD><TD>" & tabledata(4, 26) & "</TD><TD>" & tabledata(4, 27) & "</TD><TD>" & tabledata(4, 28) & "</TD></TR>" _
               & "<TR><TD>" & tabledata(5, 21) & "</TD><TD>" & tabledata(5, 22) & "</TD><TD>" & tabledata(5, 23) & "</TD><TD>" & tabledata(5, 24) & "</TD>" _
               & "<TD>" & tabledata(5, 25) & "</TD><TD>" & tabledata(5, 26) & "</TD><TD>" & tabledata(5, 27) & "</TD><TD>" & tabledata(5, 28) & "</TD></TR>" _
               & "<TR><TD>" & tabledata(6, 21) & "</TD><TD>" & tabledata(6, 22) & "</TD><TD>" & tabledata(6, 23) & "</TD><TD>" & tabledata(6, 24) & "</TD>" _
               & "<TD>" & tabledata(6, 25) & "</TD><TD>" & tabledata(6, 26) & "</TD><TD>" & tabledata(6, 27) & "</TD><TD>" & tabledata(6, 28) & "</TD></TR>" _
               & "<TR><TD>" & tabledata(7, 21) & "</TD><TD>" & tabledata(7, 22) & "</TD><TD>" & tabledata(7, 23) & "</TD><TD>" & tabledata(7, 24) & "</TD>" _
               & "<TD>" & tabledata(7, 25) & "</TD><TD>" & tabledata(7, 26) & "</TD><TD>" & tabledata(7, 27) & "</TD><TD>" & tabledata(7, 28) & "</TD></TR>" _
               & "</TABLE>"

Set MItem = OutlookApp.CreateItem(olmailitem)
With MItem
        .Subject = mailsubject
        .To = "example@xyz.com"
        .HTMLBody = mailbody
        .Save
        .Display
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Format them as you populate tabledata from the cell values based on the `j` column number:

```
For j = 21 to 28
   tabledata(2, j) = Cells(2, j).Value
Next

For i = 3 to 7
    For j = 21 to 26
       tabledata(i, j) = Cells(i, j).Value
    Next
    tabledata(i, 27) = Format(Cells(i, 27).Value, "0%")
    tabledata(i, 28) = Format(Cells(i, 28).Value, "0.00%")
Next
```

Comment: In this case `MyStr` would be a new string?

Comment: I trimmed down the excess of code and added a couple of comments that should clarify things a bit

Comment: Hopefully this makes sense, if you're not clear on where this code belongs in your sample code, let me know.